# Conflict of MouseArea with Toolbar Qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm working on making nice Ui using qml, first I have4 to make the **window frameless**, then reimplement move and resize behavior from within qml, I found an answer for that on stackoverflow. However, when I try to add some components especially a `Toolbar` inside a `ColumnLayout` or a `Column` I cannot resize the window from the **edges** where the toolbar exists.
A snippet of my code reproduces this problem try to compile it and resize the window from `top, top left or top right edges`.

> PS: I'm using Qt 6.2.1 same behavior with glitches in Qt 6.4

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Window {
    id:window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Window
    MouseArea{
        id:mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
        propagateComposedEvents: true
        property int edges: 0
        property int edgeOffset: 5

        function setEdges(x,y){
            edges = 0;
            if (x < edgeOffset) edges |= Qt.LeftEdge;
            if (x > (width - edgeOffset)) edges |= Qt.RightEdge;
            if (y < edgeOffset) edges |= Qt.TopEdge;
            if (y > (height - edgeOffset)) edges |= Qt.BottomEdge;
        }

        cursorShape: {
            return !containsMouse ? Qt.ArrowCursor:
                                    edges == 3 || edges == 12 ? Qt.SizeFDiagCursor :
                                    edges == 5 || edges == 10 ? Qt.SizeBDiagCursor :
                                    edges & 9 ? Qt.SizeVerCursor :
                                    edges & 6 ? Qt.SizeHorCursor : Qt.ArrowCursor;
        }

        onPositionChanged: setEdges(mouseX, mouseY);
        onPressed: {
            setEdges(mouseX, mouseY);
            if(edges && containsMouse){
                window.startSystemResize(edges);
            }
        }
    }

    ColumnLayout{
        width: parent.width
        height: 50
        ToolBar{
            DragHandler{
                onActiveChanged: if(active) startSystemMove()
            }

            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            RowLayout{
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                ToolButton{
                    text: "+"
                    onClicked: {
                        console.log("Hello World")
                    }
                }
                Label{
                   text: "title"
                   horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                   verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
                   Layout.fillWidth: true
                }
                ToolButton{
                    text: "x"
                    onClicked: close()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would put the `MouseArea` on top by changing the order or the `z` property and use the `MouseEvent` `accepted` property to tell the `MouseArea` that the event wasn't consumed and needs to be send further down.

But the bigger issue is that the system move in the `DragHandler` doesn't stop when releasing the mouse button. I tried to solve this by using `pressAndHold` of the `MouseArea`, but without any luck yet.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Window

    ColumnLayout {
        width: parent.width
        height: 50

        ToolBar {
            id: toolBar
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true

            RowLayout {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true

                ToolButton {
                    text: "+"
                    onClicked: console.log("Hello World")
                }
                Label {
                   text: "title"
                   horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                   verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
                   Layout.fillWidth: true
                }
                ToolButton {
                    text: "x"
                    onClicked: window.close()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton

        property int edges: 0
        property int edgeOffset: 5

        function setEdges(x, y) {
            mouseArea.edges = 0
            if (x < mouseArea.edgeOffset) mouseArea.edges |= Qt.LeftEdge
            if (x > (mouseArea.width - mouseArea.edgeOffset)) mouseArea.edges |= Qt.RightEdge
            if (y < mouseArea.edgeOffset) mouseArea.edges |= Qt.TopEdge
            if (y > (mouseArea.height - mouseArea.edgeOffset)) mouseArea.edges |= Qt.BottomEdge
        }

        cursorShape: {
            switch(mouseArea.edges) {
                case Qt.LeftEdge | Qt.TopEdge:
                case Qt.RightEdge | Qt.BottomEdge:
                    return Qt.SizeFDiagCursor
                case Qt.LeftEdge | Qt.BottomEdge:
                case Qt.RightEdge | Qt.TopEdge:
                    return Qt.SizeBDiagCursor
                case Qt.LeftEdge:
                case Qt.RightEdge:
                    return Qt.SizeHorCursor
                case Qt.TopEdge:
                case Qt.BottomEdge:
                    return Qt.SizeVerCursor
                default:
                    return Qt.ArrowCursor
            }
        }

        onPositionChanged: function(mouse) {
            mouseArea.setEdges(mouse.x, mouse.y)
        }
        onPressed: function(mouse) {
            mouseArea.setEdges(mouse.x, mouse.y)
            if (mouseArea.edges && mouseArea.containsMouse)
                window.startSystemResize(mouseArea.edges)

            mouse.accepted = mouseArea.edges
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your suggestion solved the resizing issue while keeping interaction with toolbar, however the hover effect is not working over toolbuttons. Drag is working but it has a weird issue instead of moving only the window it moves the toolbar too inside the window.

Comment: Hover effect on toolbar buttons could probably fixed by setting accepted to false in the position changed handler.

Comment: tried that but it's not working unfortunately